# Show and hide server-side errors in AngularJS 1.3+ forms

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using the Angular framework with Angular Material controls in my recent application. I'm looking for a good solution for the following problem:

A form `form` with an input field named `nickname` is shown to the user. After the user has chosen a nickname and submitted the form, the server checks whether the nickname has already been taken. In that case, it returns an error to the Angular client.

To show an appropriate error to the user, the code then calls `form.nickname.$setValidity('nicknameTaken', true)`. The new `ngMessages` module is used to display the error to the user. Further `form.$isInvalid` is used to disable the form controls to prevent the user from resubmitting the invalid nickname.

My problem is now the following: I'd like to have the error `nicknameTaken` automatically being removed as soon as the user begins to edit the form fields again. What is a good way to do this? Is there a predefined route to go when it comes to server-side validation errors of this kind? (Note that I am not asking for asynchronous validation because I only want to contact my server when the form is actually being submitted.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a normal validator directive instead. Something like

```
<input blacklist="takenNickNames" .../>
```

This directive would simply add a validator to the input, and this validator would make the input invalid if the model value is contained inside the given `takenNickNames` array (and valid if it's not present).

The `takenNickNames` array would be empty initially. When the form is submitted and the error comes back, the controller would add the invalid nick name to the array.

So, every time the user would enter something, the validator would be triggered, and would set the field valid or not, based on the taken nicknames stored in the array.

Here is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/3YkHraiZWyoHrN2rgif7?p=preview).